# how to sum all output of array textbox in another textbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

So i have an array list of textbox and i want to sum up all of the value of it. In this code it just add for the last text box.how can i do it? Im thinking of for doing a for each but i dont know the right code for it. i need some help please.

```
Private Sub boxunitpricecom(ByRef boxpoqty As TextBox, ByRef boxpounitprice As TextBox, ByRef boxpoamount As TextBox)
        'MessageBox.Show("right")

        Dim var1 As String
        Dim var2 As String
        Dim var3 As String
        Dim var4 As String
        Dim amount As String

        Try

            var1 = Val(boxpoqty.Text)
            var2 = Val(boxpounitprice.Text)
            var3 = var1 * var2
            boxpoamount.Text = var3
            'var4 = boxpoamount.Text
            'amount = Val(var4) + Val(var4)

            ' txttotalamount.Text = amount
            Dim arrLst As New ArrayList
            Dim dblVal As Double

            dblVal = 0.0
            For i = 0 To arrLst.Count - 1
                dblVal = dblVal + boxpoamount.Text
            Next
            |
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim txt As TextBox
    Dim Sum As Integer
    For I = 1 To TextboxCount
       txt = CType(Me.Controls("TextBox" + I.ToString()), TextBox) 'the name property of textbox
       Sum = Sum + Integer.Parse(txt.Text)
    Next I

Output.Text = Sum.ToString()
```

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @JaemineSanchez I don't know the textbox names or where they are (in my code I have assumed that they are directly on form otherwise you should change `Me` in `Me.Controls` to the parent of the textboxes. this is only showing the way. the exact code will not work for you.

Comment: but it is possible to work there? should the txt.text is where the output should show?

Comment: it didnt show error anymore but the output is only the double of the last text box.

Comment: name your textbox array like `txt1`, `txt2`, `txt3` , ... and then get them like:  `txt = CType(Me.Controls("txt" + I.ToString()), TextBox)`

Comment: i put my textbox and it just times the number of output to how many textbox i include